# How do I efficiently check presence of variable in a set?

Tags: python, list, syntax, set, keyword

I am working on a logic that if any of the 3 variables (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`) is `None` certain function `foo()` cannot be called. The code I used is:

```
if None in {var1, var2, var3}:
    print("some variable is None")
```

However it raises and exception: `unhashable type: 'list'`. It works perfectly fine if I use:

```
if None in [var1, var2, var3]:
    print("some variable is None")
```

But the caveat is it only happens when I implement this logic in my GUI Application having many classes and ~3000 lines of code. If I test this logic in a dummy script, it works perfectly fine for both sets `{}` and lists `()`. **I cant seem to understand what's going on over here**. My dummy script is:

```
class my_class:
    a = {None, 32, 44}

    def check(self):
        if None in self.a:
            print("some variable is None")
            return None
        foo()

cls = my_class
cls.foo(cls)
```

Comment: Presumably `varX` are lists? Could you switch to tuples, which *can* go in sets?

Comment: If it works with `in [...]`, why not use it? Or something like `any(i is None for i in (var1, var2, var3))`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean by "which can go in sets"? I thought we could use any object inside sets?

Comment: No, you can only put hashable objects in sets, hence the error.

Comment: @AsadUllahButt The most efficient method is simply `if var1 is None or var2 is None or var3 is None:`, because it short-circuits and it doesn't have to create an intermediate container object.